# Word for "partially buried"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

Example:

> They sat on the lower part of the beach, [...] in the sand.

The word *buried* would imply they are completely or almost completely beneath the sand. Is there a word to show they are just partially (e.g. only their buttocks) immersed in the sand?

Comment: This question is funny to me because it seems akin to:  The man lay sprawled on the ground [...].  The word *dead* would imply that his life had ended. Is there a word to show that his life had only partially ended (e.g., his knee was scraped up)?

Comment: *partially buried* is the best option IMO!

Comment: *buried up to their [extremity]*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[*Settle*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=settle)

> To cause to sink, become compact, or come to rest; to move downward; sink or descend, especially gradually.  (The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

They can also *nestle* into the sand. Nestle implies partially obscuring, or settling into (similar to) a nest.

[*Ensconced*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ensconced):

> To settle (oneself) securely or comfortably. (AHDEL)

Comment: Nestled also has the right feel, I think, like the definition given here of *ensconced*, without making the reader wonder where you pulled that word from.

One might even go with "comfortably nestled into" the sand.

Answer (score 14):

When it comes to partial burial, there can be no more obvious Germanic choice than ***half-buried***, with learnèd Latinate alternatives *semi-interred, semi-inhumed,* and *semi-intumulated* available for those faint not of heart nor pen.

All would be grave terms indeed, especially the Latinate ones, and at risk for tenebrous overtones anywhere this side of the lich-gate — and surety of such on its far side.

Comment: I had to look up *lich*, is it only used in fantasy fiction?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, and I did not mean it in the fantasy-fiction sense. A *lich* is simply a corpse. So the *lich-gate* is (per the OED) “The roofed gateway to a churchyard under which the corpse is set down, to await the clergyman’s arrival.” There are lots of *lich-XXX* compounds, where *XXX* includes *house, path, yard*, and *stone* — plus many others. A *lichyard* is of course  a graveyard. It is an old and venerable word to be sure, and is “archaic” when used outside of its compounds. It was a common word in Old English, and appears several times in *Beowulf*. It is still normal in Dutch.

Comment: That's probably going to be the most interesting piece of information I'm going to read all day. That was nice, thanks!

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is also one of two English descendants of the Common Germanic noun, _*līko-_ ‘form, shape, appearance, body’, whose other descendant is _like_, originally meaning ‘likeness, shape [of]’. This latter is in turn what underlies the (originally adjectival, now mostly adverbial) suffix _-ly_ in English (_-lich_ in German, _-lijk_ in Dutch, etc.) in a form reduced by its unstressed position—compare cases where it’s been attached as a whole word more recently, such as _childlike_ (which was actually _childly_ earlier on, but then got ‘reinvented’).

Comment: You've certainly laid this one half to rest.

Comment: The spelling 'lych gate' is far more common; as @Mari-LouA said 'lich' is primarily used in fantasy literature.

Comment: @PeteKirkham You’re right, but the [historical usage pattern](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lychgate%2Clichgate&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clychgate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clichgate%3B%2Cc0) is intriguing. It appears to have plunged for both spellings during both World Wars; there ***must*** be a reason for that! There was also a surge in the *lichgate* spelling unparalleled in the *lychgate* one in the late 1800s, which I have even less of a notion about the cause of than I might guess the two WW plunges might be from.

Answer (score 8):

**Sunk**, the past participle of *sink*.

From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sunk)

> 2. move to lower level
> 3. fall/sit/lie down

For example

> They sat on the lower part of the beach, *sunk* in the sand.

Answer (score 7):

It's not technical, but 'planted' in the sand is the visual I get from your description.

Answer (score 5):

> They sat on the lower part of the beach, their bottoms **wedged** in the sand.
>   They sat on the lower part of the beach, their bottoms **stuck** in the sand

You can omit *their bottoms* and it would still make sense, but it would be less amusing.

Comment: "their bottoms firmly in the grips of sand-wedgies"

Answer (score 4):

In general the best way to say "partially buried" is "partially buried".

For your example sentence though, I think this is a good idiomatic way of saying it:

> They sat on the lower part of the beach, butts in the sand.

"Lower part" isn't really very natural though... do you mean right next to the water?

Answer (score 3):

'Settled' implies resting comfortably on the sand or 'partially covered' suggests the sand comes somewhat higher without entombing them.

Comment: Can you make a kind of distinction from the answer already given?

Answer (score 2):

Below are several options;  multiple options are provided because you can use them to search for more synonyms if these don't serve your needs.

Embedded, imprinted, sunken, cupped, indented, incurved

Answer (score 1):

I am shocked that no one has suggested "entrenched".

If you are careful to set up the proper context, you can avoid drawing out the trench aspect, and draw the mind of the reader to the more common modern usage, indicating "half buried" or "firmly set it place".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your term is going to depend on the mood you want to convey. 'Entrenched', 'buried' sound more like a hostile or engulfing environment to me, whereas 'cupped' (my personal favourite) and 'settled' imply a nurturing place, a calm and cordial conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The many great answers here suggest that this particular word blank is a great opportunity to not merely adequately describe the particular physical aspect of being half-buried, but to also give the scene some context or flavor.

For example, **nestled** implies a certain level of coziness and agreeable disposition, whereas **stuck** obviously implies something a little more troubling. Maybe they're not just stuck in the sand, they're stuck in an emotional rut!

Also, consider this an opportunity to stretch your reader's imaginations a little - perhaps the sand can be considered as a metaphor: a security blanket, an impish spirit, a caressing Mother Earth, lost time, a growing problem?

Some other suggestions, then, that might set a certain mood or tone or be appropriate to the context:

- **mired** in the sand (despair / downhill trajectory )
- **snared** in the sand ( unpleasant surprises )
- **embrangled** in the sand ( belligerence / fighting )
- **embraced** by the sand ( sand as friend )
- **attired** in sand ( sand as clothes, dash of irony as attired usually means evening gowns and tuxedos )
- **half-swallowed** by sand ( sand as the abyss )
- their bodies **greatly diminished** by sand
- **slowly gnawed on** by sand ( sand as problem )

There are of course plenty of literal choices as the above answers indicate, but the wonderful thing about writing is it provides you opportunities to employ a more purposeful diction to convey themes, mood, and even complex emotions with a sharp turn of phrase.